# How to make ranking system in PHP

Tags: php, ranking

I have problem. . 
In my case i make championship. . You know, the winner is determined by the highest value. . 
Example :

```
$sql = "SELECT bla bla bla FROM `user` ORDER BY `point` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $1++;
    echo "rank ".$i." is ".$row['name']." with point ".$row['point'].";
}
```

It's will show

- rank 1 is abc with point 10
- rank 2 is def with point 9
- rank 3 is ghi with point 8
- rank 4 is jkl with point 7
- rank 5 is mno with point 7
- rank 6 is pqr with point 3
- rank 7 is stu with point 1

The question. .

1. look the result. . rank 4 and rank 5 have same point. . how to make
   they in same possition ??
2. how to auto detect title of champions like rank 1 is the big boss, rank 2 is a boss, rank 7 is worker ??
3. how to tell ex: you in possition 6 ??

Comment: `$1++;` o_O ....

Comment: For your first question,*hint:* just don't increment `$i` if point is same as the previous point.

Comment: @Rikesh: usually when multiple players have same scores - they take the same place but place is incremented. Like A and B are on the first place, and C is on the 3rd place.

Answer (score 6):

```
$sql = "SELECT bla bla bla FROM `user` ORDER BY `point` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if( !$result ){
  echo 'SQL Query Failed';
}else{

  $rank = 0;
  $last_score = false;
  $rows = 0;

  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $rows++;
    if( $last_score!= $row['point'] ){
      $last_score = $row['point'];
      $rank = $rows;
    }
    echo "rank ".$rank." is ".$row['name']." with point ".$row['point'].";
  }
}
```

This code will also adjust the rankings properly - such as:

```
rank 1 is Adam Aarons with point 100
rank 2 is Barry Blue with point 90
rank 2 is Betty Boop with point 90
rank 4 is Charlie Chaplin with point 80
```

Note that there is no "rank 3", as "Charlie Chaplin" is actually the fourth-highest scorer.

If you do not want this behaviour, then simply replace `$rank = $rows;` with `$rank++;`

Answer (score 1):

ad 1. group by point, add @curRow := \@curRow + 1 AS row_numbe to select the current row number which will be the rank position

ad 2. left join title_dict on row_number = title_dict.id

where title dictionary is table with title_id and title name dictionary

ad 3. select from your select on id = your id

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` --- OP asked about mysql, not oracle

Comment: I meant usage of variable storing the current row number added to the statement \@curRow := \@curRow + 1 AS row_number like this, sorry for this stupid comment that didn't explain anything.

Comment: so put it in the answer. OP has no idea what you're talking about

Comment: Like this dude. . SELECT l.user_id, l.name, l.point, \@curRow := \@curRow + 1 AS rank FROM user l LEFT JOIN level ON rank = level_id JOIN (SELECT \@curRow := 0) r ORDER BY point DESC but this is error unknown column rank in joining table if not join with table level it's work thank's

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a very easy way to order players with same amount of points is to add a column "points_last_update" containing the timestamp of the last update to the "points" column. Then you just add the "points_last_update" to the ORDER BY in your sql statement. That way, the player who has reached the points the first gets the higher ranking, wich is logic.

Comment: If the score table is insert only and has a auto incrementing primary key, then the primary key maybe used in a similar way as an explicit time stamp column. However I agree and explicit column is better.

Answer (score 0):

Save the last score and make sure it does not equal the current score before you increment.

```
$sql = "SELECT bla bla bla FROM `user` ORDER BY `point` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
$lastscore = NULL;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if ($lastscore != $row['point']){
   $i++;
   }
   echo "rank ".$i." is ".$row['name']." with point ".$row['point'];
   $lastscore = $row['point'];
}
```